# CSS Selector: Tabs not staying selected

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

When a tab is selected, I want this tab to stay selected and behave as this CodePen: [Light & Sexy Tabs](https://codepen.io/CoffeeCupDrummer/pen/qmIdx)

Not quite sure why when I'm pressing one of my tabs it is not staying selected. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Report 01</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Production Report">
    <meta name="author" content="Me">
    


<!--    <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chartjs-plugin-crosshair.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.min-6.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zebra_dialog.src-3.0.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/CreateGraphics.04.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Report.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Zebra/classic/zebra_dialog.css">
<!-- Preventing Browser Requests for favicon.ico -->
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">

</head>

<style>

    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        border: 0;
        display: block;  /* No floating content on sides */
    }

</style>

<body>

<!-- <body onload="CreateGraphics()"> -->
    </br>
    <input type="file" name="" id="file" accept=".csv, .pdf" class="inputfile" onchange="SelectCSVFile(event)" hidden />
    <label for="file" id="Selector">Upload a .CSV File: </label>
    
    <div class="Wrapper">
        <header class="tabs group">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#SummaryTab">Summary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#GlobalViewTab">Global View</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Arm1Tab">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Arm2Tab">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Arm3Tab">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Arm4Tab">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#RawDataTab">Raw Data</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <section class="Content">
            <div id="SummaryTab">
                <h3>Summary</h3>
                <p>This is the Summray Tab content.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="GlobalViewTab">
                <h3>Global</h3>
                <p>This is the Global View Tab content.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Arm1Tab">
                <h3>Arm 1</h3>
                <p>This is the Arm1 Tab content.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Arm2Tab">
                <h3>Arm 2</h3>
                <p>This is the Arm2 Tab content.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Arm3Tab">
                <h3>Arm 3</h3>
                <p>This is the Arm3 Tab content.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Arm4Tab">
                <h3>Arm 4</h3>
                <p>This is the Arm4 Tab content.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="RawDataTab">
                <h3>Raw Data</h3>
                <p>This is Raw Data Tab content.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    </br> 

    <div id='ModeGraph' class="split" style='position:absolute; left:px; top:540px;'>
        <canvas id="CanvasCartMode" width=1350px height=300px></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id='OvenGraph' class="split" style='position:absolute; left:0px; top:860px'>
        <canvas id="CanvasOvenTemp" width=1350px height=600px></canvas></div>
    </div>
    </br>   

    <script>

        Chart.defaults.global.title.fontSize = 24;
        Chart.defaults.global.title.fontColor = 'red';
        Chart.defaults.global.title.fontStyle = 'bold';

    </script>
<!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ValidateFile.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Main.05.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
body {font-family: Arial;}

.inputfile + label {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    background-color: #545f60;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.inputfile:focus + label,
.inputfile + label:hover {
    background-color: red;
    outline: 1px dotted #000;
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.tabs ul {
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
.tabs ul li {   
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
  }
.tabs ul li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #6edeef;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 8px 12px 25px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 8px 12px 25px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 8px 12px 25px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s ease, margin 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.2s ease, margin 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: padding 0.2s ease, margin 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition: padding 0.2s ease, margin 0.2s ease;
    transition: padding 0.2s ease, margin 0.2s ease;
}


.tabs li a {
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.tabs ul li a:hover {
    margin: 35px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
}

.tabs ul li a:active {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background: #545f60;
    color: #6edeef;
    z-index: 4;
    outline: none;
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.Content {
    background: #545f60;
    color:white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 8px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 8px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 8px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
/* Hide all Tabs content but first content div */
.Content div:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

```
$(function() {
    $(".tabs a").click(function() {
  
        // Check for active
        $(".tabs li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");

        // Display active tab
        let currentTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".Content div").hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
        

        return false;
    });
});
```

Anyone sees what is wrong in my CSS? I did go through this web site [Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/rule.htm), but did not find what I'm missing. I'm new to programming. Thanks!

Comment: Your active class is not on the anchor, it's on the `li`?

Comment: Also there is no `active` class in your CSS/

Comment: @Paulie_D and @Man Ng, thanks! Based on both of your comments, changing it to ```.tabs ul li.active a```, does select it. But now, they all stay selected.

Comment: @Paulie_D, not quite sure to understand what you mean by "There is no ```active```" in your CSS. I thought classes are defined in my HTML and then used in the CSS as ```.active``` or ```:active```.

Comment: You do not have a class of active in your CSS `.active` does not appear and `:active` is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is your issue

`.tabs ul li a:active {`

it should be

`.tabs ul li a.active {`

This will target the class of `active`

The second issue you are having is in your JS
`$(".tabs li a").removeClass("active");`

You need to remove the class `active` from the `li`, not from you `a` elements.

`$(".tabs li").removeClass("active");`

Try this